# Why and how to generate the ic_launcher.webp icons inside mipmap folder

Tags: webp, android-asset-studio

Android Studio used to generate PNG files for the launcher icons but with the last version, when you create a new project, the default launcher icons inside the *mipmap* folders are in **WEBP** format.

I tried to find anything about it but this change is not addressed anywhere. The thing is that if you try to add a new image asset and replace these icons, the generator will create **PNG** files and you'll have to manually delete the WEBP files.

So, what should one do? Does the **Asset Studio** have an option for exporting them as WEBP? Is WEBP actually better than PNG (specially for older devices, say API level 21)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

webp is smaller in file size but requires Android 4.3 (API 18)+ for foreground transparency.

At the moment, you still need to manually convert those generated png icons into webp. Android Studio has [built-in support](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/convert-webp) for this conversion.

Alternatively, you can use Google's command line tool:

1. get the encoder: https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/precompiled (see "downloads repository")
2. convert icons: `./bin/cwebp ./ic_launcher.png -q 100 -o ./ic_launcher.webp`

Comment: it's always skip files